# spelling of "layed off" as in "lay off from a job

Tags: orthography

I am writing a resume. I am stuck on how to spell a word. 
In a case of loosing a job due to a lay off, is it spelled "layed" or "laid?"

Thank you,
Barbara

Comment: I never see it as "layed"; I'm not even sure that that's a valid spelling for the word in any sense.

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/laid-off

Comment: Hello, Barbara. You could check in a dictionary, as with the spelling of "losing" as in "losing a job".

Answer (score 2):

"Laid off" is the term you are looking for. It is the past tense form of the phrase "lay off" in terms of losing a job.